# Cannot create output file with saveas

Tags: matlab, load

i wrote that code

```
   clear all;
clc;

addpath('C:\Users\John\Documents\MATLAB\code for yannis\anger(W)\');


h1 = dir('C:\Users\John\Documents\MATLAB\code for yannis\anger(W)\');

for i=3:numel(h1)
    %disp(h1(i,1).name);

    %disp(k);
    three(h1(i,1).name);
end
```

and the three function is

```
    function  three(filename)
%disp(filename);
q = char(39);
filename = strcat(q,filename,q)

%disp(filename);
load(filename);
```

And i get that error:
Error using load
Unable to read file '03a01WaM.mat': No such file or directory.

Error in three (line 7)
load(filename);

Error in run_three (line 13)
    three(h1(i,1).name);

i also wrote  exist('03a01WaM.mat') and the function return 2

Does anyone has an idea, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The filename is `03a01WaM.mat`, but you are trying to access `'03a01WaM.mat'`. Try it without the additional apostrophe.

Comment: If the answers has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and this is no longer an open question. If your question is not answered, please explain what’s missing.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your code.

- `addpath` is simply unnessecary.
- You are using relative path, but not `cd`. You have to use the full path to access the files.
- You are adding a apostrophe to the filename.

Correct code would be:

```
directory='C:\Users\John\Documents\MATLAB\code for yannis\anger(W)\'; %'
h1 = dir(directory);

for i=3:numel(h1)
   filename=fullfile(directory,h1(i,1).name);
   load(filename);
end
```

Comment: another issue with OP code - you rarely need to use `clear all` - `clear` is usually suffice.